# How to create a histogram (bar chart) to compare items between groups over 3 years?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, charts

I would like to plot a bar chart (histogram) to compare the items (X, Y, total) between 2 groups over 3 years using MS Excel 2010. For example,

```
           2016     2017   2018
Group A   
Item X      20        30     40
Item Y      20        40     50
Total       40        70     90

Group B
Item X      30        40     50
Item Y      30        50     100
Total       60        90     150
```

How to plot a histogram/bar chart that shows the total (added up by X and Y) of Group A and compare the same total with group B over 3 years ? I tried "Stacked column" in Excel 2010 but couldn't get what I wanted.

Grateful if any of you can give me some help.

Lee has just posted comment a graph. Yes, it was almost what I wanted. Pls show me the steps. Just wonder if each stacked bar can also show relative contribution of X and Y (by different size or colored of segments within the vertical bar. This will help compare the X and Y of Gp A to that of Gp B visually. Thanks.

kenny

Comment: (1) What have you tried?  (2) Thank you for providing sample input data, but it’s hard for us to help you reach your goal if you don’t show us (or explain better) what result you want.  … … … …  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: Do you want to get the result like this: https://imgur.com/a/navgW  If yes, I can help you post the steps, if not please provide more information about your problem.

Comment: Thank, Lee for your prompt response. Yes, your graph is almost what I wanted. Can the each bar also show the relative contribution of item X and Y? ie the yellow bar of Group A is composed of two segments with different color (X, Y) in one single vertical block, and the blue of B also shows the same. In this case, the size of segment X in A and the size of segment X in B (so as Y) can be compared visually. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily with a Pivot Table, and a Pivot Chart, but you need to have your data in another format first.

I made an example below. Simply arrange your data like the green table, then insert a Pivot Table. You must use a structure similar to mine (i.e. `Items` in columns, `Years` and `Groups` in rows).

Finally, insert a Pivot Chart linked to that Pivot Table. Use the `Stacked Columns` chart to have both items stacked together.

If you rearrange the pivot table (for instance, if you switch `Years` and `Items`), you can have other useful analysis as well.

[image]